# Facing an AssertionError in from a Pixel Nerf model

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, computer-vision, data-science

> I am using [this](https://github.com/sxyu/pixel-nerf) model from github, Form this library we can generate a video from 1,2 or 3 images.
> By Running this command
> `(!python eval/gen_video.py -n srn_car  --split test -P '64 104' -D "/content/drive/MyDrive/pixel-nerf/test/000000.png" -S 1)`

**The Actual command given on the link**

```
python eval/gen_video.py -n srn_car --gpu_id=<GPU (s)> --split test -P '64 104' -D <srn data dir>/cars -S
```

i removed gpu_id because i am running code on google colab.

This is the path of the image i placed in the test dir. (/content/drive/MyDrive/pixel-nerf/test/000000.png")

**Error i am facing**

```
EXPERIMENT NAME: srn_car
* Config file: conf/exp/srn.conf
* Dataset format: srn
* Dataset location: /content/drive/MyDrive/pixel-nerf/test/000000.png
Loading SRN dataset /content/drive/MyDrive/pixel-nerf/test/000000.png_test name: 000000.png
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "eval/gen_video.py", line 69, in <module>
args.dataset_format, args.datadir, want_split=args.split, training=False
File "/content/drive/My Drive/pixel-nerf/src/data/__init__.py", line 62, in get_split_dataset
test_set = dset_class(datadir, stage="test", **flags, **kwargs)
File "/content/drive/My Drive/pixel-nerf/src/data/SRNDataset.py", line 29, in __init__
assert os.path.exists(self.base_path)
AssertionError
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just in case you are still interested in the above question. -D stands for dataset directory and not the image location. So as per the example given in the Github link, the folder structure is like :

srn_dataset/chairs_train
srn_dataset/chairs_eval
srn_dataset/chairs_test

Thus the syntax will be for evaluation will be : python eval/gen_video.py -n srn_chair --split test -P '64 104' -D srn_dataset/chairs -S 1

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer. I have solved it already but thanks for the answer. Hope it will help others as well.